# Bootstrap carousel indicators and controls not working from php

Tags: php, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using php to search a database in order to get pictures for my Carousel, it loads the pictures, and cycles in time, **but whenever I click on the side arrows or the indicators, it does nothing**, I tried changing the jQuery version (which seemed to be the solution in all the past questions I checked) but it didn't work... is it because I'm loading it from php?

**The PHP code:**

```
$count = 0;
forEach($filas as $fila){
        $idimg = $fila['id_imagen'];
        if($count==0){
          $indicator .= '<li data-target="#imagenes" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>';
          $inner .= '<div class="item active"><img class="img-responsive center-block" src="getimg.php?id='.$idprod.'&img='.$idimg.'" alt="'.$nprod.'"></div>';
        }else{
          $indicator .= '<li data-target="#imagenes" data-slide-to="'.$count.'"></li>';
          $inner .= '<div class="item"><img class="img-responsive center-block" src="getimg.php?id='.$idprod.'&img='.$idimg.'" alt="'.$nprod.'"></div>';
        }
        $count++;
      }
```

**The HTML markup**

```
        <div class="carousel-slide" id="imagenes" data-ride="carousel">
          <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <?php print("$indicator");?>
          </ol>
          <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
            <?php print("$inner");?>
          </div>

          <!-- Left and right controls -->
          <a class="left carousel-control" href="#imagenes" role="button" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          </a>
          <a class="right carousel-control" href="#imagenes" role="button" data-slide="next">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          </a>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of attemps I finally managed to see my error, and I must absolutely apologise for not noticing it, on my markup I typed in class="carousel-slide" instead of "carousel slide"... fixed that and it's now working flawlessly.

Answer (score 0):

i can't add the comment, so there is my suggestion on the problem.
There reason is jquery carousel fired on `$(document).ready()`, but you are loading content dynamically, so you need to apply `$(..).carousel()` after the load or write own trigger for the navigation like so

```
$(document).on('#left','click',function(){
  $('.carousel').carousel('prev');
});
```

1. Try own navigations. Here is the jsfiddle example of the bootstrap carousel navigations methods - https://jsfiddle.net/Lomj9k4j/1/
2. Try to fire `$('.carousel').carousel()` on document ready

   `$(document).ready(){
     $('.carousel').carousel();
   });`

usefull link - http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel

Comment: and its better to you classes not ids and you can retrieve carousel 'id' using `attr('href')` or `attr('data-target')`

Comment: I'm not entirely sure I understand what you mean by $(..).carousel(), do you mean the definition in bootstrap.js? should I add the trigger inside my php?

Comment: for example you can create own navigation arrows with ids `#left` and `#right`, and if you look at this page http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel, there is "methods" for a carousel. In  this example to get to work the arrows, you just add this code to your template file or main.js file (don't edit bootstrap.js)
`$(function() {
$('#left').click(function() {
$('.carousel').carousel('prev');
});
$('#right').click(function() {
$('.carousel').carousel('next');
});
})` and there is also method `.carousel(number)` where `number` is the number of the item (starting from 0)

Comment: I made a jsfiddle example for you - https://jsfiddle.net/Lomj9k4j/1/

let me edit my answer with it

Comment: Although I learned a lot from what you wrote, it wasn't the problem, I've solved it, but I'm really grateful for your teachings, thanks a lot really!